# Unexpected token in D3 version 3.4.11

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I recently downloaded the newest version of d3, version 3.4.11. I am trying to reference the d3 file, but when I run the html page in Chrome, the console returns an "Unexpected token &" error on this line:

```
var &#960; = Math.PI, &#964; = 2 * &#960;, half&#960; = &#960; / 2, &#949; = 1e-6, &#949;2 = &#949; * &#949;, d3_radians = &#960; / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / &#960;;
```

I have tried adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to the top of my html page, but this doesn't fix the error. Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I think I may have found the problem, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

The original line looks like this:

```
var π = Math.PI, τ = 2 * π, halfπ = π / 2, ε = 1e-6, ε2 = ε * ε, d3_radians = π / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / π;
```

But when I select all, copy, and paste the text into another page the output looks like the code at the top:

```
var &#960; = Math.PI, &#964; = 2 * &#960;, half&#960; = &#960; / 2, &#949; = 1e-6, &#949;2 = &#949; * &#949;, d3_radians = &#960; / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / &#960;;
```

All of the symbols are replaced by number values, but when I run the page not all of them are recognized, hence the "Unexpected Token &" error.

Therefore, I need a way to copy the file I downloaded onto another page. I cannot reference the original file because the page I need to reference exists on the web so that other users can reference the same file as well without having to download d3.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the browser? The file may be cached.

Comment: How did you download that file? It seems, the variables were replaced by HTML entities ...

Comment: @Lars Yes. I have also tried clearing the cached images and files from the browser.

Comment: @Sirko I downloaded the file from d3js.org and unzipped the file

Comment: @user3798384 Just went there and downloaded the file. But I can't find your line in there. How do you reference it?

Comment: @Sirko The line is not located in the file I downloaded, but when I copy that file to the page I'm referencing it adds the line that produces the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3798384 I assume you are doing something really weird. Maybe you could add your HTML code as well?

Comment: while you technically _can_ use these variable names, i personally would not do so. They are hard to type, and as you experienced, come with other problems attached.

Comment: @amenthes the symbol variable names are in the original d3 source code, as a way of creating short but meaningful names.  Re the original question: why are you copying the library into a new file, and what editor are you using to create it?  A good editor shouldn't be inserting HTML entities in scripts.

Comment: @AmeliaBR I am using Intuit QuickBase pages. Those symbols must not be supported in the editor.

Comment: Your best bet might be to ask for help on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/), specifically tagging the question to indicate the software you're using.